# An interesting inequality $(mn)^\alpha\le/(?\ge) p(np)^\alpha+q(mq)^\alpha$

Tags: inequality

Let positive real numbers $p$, $q$, $m$ and $n$ satisfy $p+q=1$ and $m+n=1$, and for real $\alpha$ when

1. $\alpha\in[-1,0]$
   \begin{align}
   p(np)^\alpha+q(mq)^\alpha\le (mn)^\alpha
   \end{align}
2. $\alpha\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(0,\infty)$
   \begin{align}
   (mn)^\alpha\le p(np)^\alpha+q(mq)^\alpha
   \end{align}

I proved them by applying Bernoulli's inequalities, but what I am looking for is something simpler for lower graders to understand. The expansion (substituting $q=1-p$ and $m=1-n$) by binomials has been tried but the factorial form cannot be explicitly utilized for me.

Comment: Is Jensen inequality allowed?

Comment: https://yourimageshare.com/ib/2Gruh3alEG
Here is how I would do it with Jensen, it only uses the simple inequality with 2 coefficients (p and 1-p)
It's maybe still too complicated, though Jensen is just seeing that the segment between two points of the curve is always higher than the curve in a convex function, and then just translate this fact algebraically for each point of the interior of the segment

Comment: @Nithuya, it is will be rude to exclude Jensen's inequality, and your approach is one nice answer which I myself haven't figured it out before. Sorry!

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting first inequality, dividing it by $(mn)^{\alpha}$ and then changing the exponents becomes:
$$p(\frac{m}{p})^{-\alpha} + q(\frac{n}{q})^{-\alpha} \leq 1$$
Note that if $-1 \leq \alpha \leq 0$  then $0 \leq -\alpha \leq 1$ and function $x^{-\alpha}$ is concave, which means using Jensen inequality with $f(x) = x^{\alpha}$ and coefficients $p,q$ (we have $p+q = 1$):
$$p(\frac{m}{p})^{-\alpha} + q(\frac{n}{q})^{-\alpha} \leq (p\frac{m}{p} + q\frac{n}{q})^{-\alpha} = (m+n)^{-\alpha} = 1$$

The other inequality is the exact same reasonning but knowing $x^{-\alpha}$ is convex if $-\alpha \not \in [0,1]$.